# Why am I getting a "Type Mismatch" error when running the following formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-formula, type-mismatch

ROUND(SUMIFS($L$3:$L$14,$K$3:$K$14,0.5)/1000,0)

```
Dim A As Range
Dim B As Range
Set A = Range("L" & FirstRow, "L" & LastRow2)
Set B = Range("K" & FirstRow, "K" & LastRow2)

Range("T7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A & "," & B & ",0.5)/1000,0)"
```

Comment: Try `Range("T7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A.Address & "," & B.Address & ",0.5)/1000,0)"`

Comment: Thanks @SuperSymmetry this works and is also the more intuitive solution. How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Glad that it worked. I added an answer, thanks.

Comment: Why is the first line separated from the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Range("T7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A.Address & "," & B.Address & ",0.5)/1000,0)"
```

**Explanation of the error:**

Your line

```
Range("T7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A & "," & B & ",0.5)/1000,0)"
```

is equivalent to

```
Range("T7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A.Value & "," & B.Value & ",0.5)/1000,0)"
```

because `.Value` is the default property of a `Range` object in VBA.

Since `A` and `B` are both multi-contiguous-cells ranges, `.Value` returns a two-dimensional array of all values of these ranges. Therefore, you are trying to concatenate `String`s to two-dimensional arrays, resulting in a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a type mismatch, because the `range.formula` is expecting `String value` and you are combining `Range with String`, and it causes the error. To solve it, *redim*ing your variable from `Range to String` will do, for example:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, firstrow As Long
Dim A As String
Dim B As String

firstrow = 1
lastrow = 20

A = "L" & CStr(firstrow) & ":L" & CStr(lastrow)
B = "K" & CStr(firstrow) & ":K" & CStr(lastrow)

Range("B7").Formula = "=Round(SumIfs(" & A & "," & B & ",0.5)/1000,0)"
```

Comment: Actually OP is mixing `String` with 2-d arrays. The formula is read as `"=Round(SumIfs(" & A.Value & "," & B.Value & ",0.5)/1000,0)"`. Because `A` and `B` are multi-cell ranges `.Value` returns a 2-d array. If this is everything the OP is doing then your solution is a good optimisation. However, the OP might need these ranges later in the code. A simple fix that keeps the OP's logic is to use `A.Address` and `B.Address`. Also `CStr` is not necessary here.

Comment: @I not sure about your 2d array, but using string is easier to understand in my case and both method should be work, anyway thanks.